# Как переменной присвоить значение изображения?

Tags: javascript, html5

Как, используя jQuery, переменной присвоить значение изображения и вывести эту картинку на экран в определенный момент, когда отработает функция)?

Comment: Что понимается под "значением изображения"? Ссылку на изображение? Base 64 encode? И что пытались сделать самостоятельно?

Comment: var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "свин.png";
jQuery('#vash_rezultat').val(rezultat+img);

Comment: не судите строго, я пока пытаюсь разобраться опытным путем в JS и jQuery мне надо что бы вместе с результатом появлялась картинка бьюсь неделю, но немогу понять как это осуществить. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Т.е. Вам надо при определенных условиях создавать на странице img с определенным src, выводить картинку на экран, а саму ссылку на изображение выводить в каком-нибудь элементе, например в input'e? Выводить значение Вы хотите с полным путем (/bigDir/images/svin.png) или только саму картинку (svin.png)?

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли. Картинка находится в папке с файлами поэтому svin.png

Comment: так, отлично. Теперь добавьте эту информацию в сам вопрос и свой код, который пытались вкрутить, тоже закиньте (там есть кнопка "править"), - чтобы другим не пришлось читать комментарии, а смысл проблемы был понятен сразу. И почему из Вас всё щипцами пришлось вытягивать? =)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понял из обсуждения в комментариях, нужно примерно это:

```js
function showImgName(imgSrc) {
  var filename = imgSrc.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  $('#imgNameContainer').html(filename);
}

function createImg(imgSrc) {
  var newImg = $("<img>");
      newImg.attr("src", imgSrc);
      newImg.appendTo("#imgContainer");
  
  /* 
  //Более коротка запись, которая не сработает в старых IE
  //Но если их поддержка не нужна, то можно воспользоваться этим:
  var newImg = $('<img />', { src: imgSrc });
  newImg.appendTo('#imgContainer');
  */
  
  showImgName(imgSrc);
}

function callImgCreation() {
  //Здесь находится тело функции в результате выполнения
  //которой, выбирается нужная ссылка на картинку
  //и вызывается функция создания картинки
  createImg('http://ru.wikifur.com/w/images/b/bc/Spanky_Ham.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgContainer">
    <!-- Сюда пойдет новое изображение -->
</div>
<span id="imgNameContainer">
  <!-- Сюда пойдет имя изображения, напр. 'svin.png' -->
</span>
<button onclick="callImgCreation()">Показать</button>
```

[Ссылка на тикет](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8900) описывающий, почему не сработает более короткая запись в старых IE.

Answer (score -1):

```
var MyImg = 'svin.png';
$('img').attr('src', MyImg);
```

так будет добавляться картинка во все теги img. Для детальной информации выложите свой код, чтоб понять куда и после чего добавлять эту картинку